# Can you make a new Borderlands 2 character and leave off where your old character was?

Tags: borderlands-2

Im hoping to make a new character with a different class, but I wanna know if I will get my weapons, level and progress back. Will I have to start from scratch?

Answer (score 11):

Starting a new character starts over from scratch.  The only weapons that can "carry over" are the ones you put in the stash by claptrap.

Comment: ...which is only accessible when you reach sanctuary which is already a few hours into the game.

Comment: Not to mention you gotta collect all those brown rocks for claptrap to get it :P.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you would have to start from scratch. There is no built-in way to change the class and keeping all progress.

However, if you don't mind the downsides, you can use [Gibbed save editor](http://blog.gib.me/2014/07/15/borderlands-2-save-editor-revision-237/). Remember to **back up your current save files** before experimenting.

[image: Gibbed interface]

As you can see in the picture, after choosing your save file you can simply change the class of your character using the dropdown menu. Then click Save and run the game.

Aforementioned downsides:

- Since it's not a competitive game I wouldn't call it cheating, but it can make you feel "dirty", especially when you use it to level up or get legendary weapons with zero effort.
- You don't get used to the way the new character plays in a natural way. Instead, you're given X skill points without knowing how to use them efficiently.